# Node.js / Express.js can't get body response from API call via Request middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I'm trying to learn Node.js via Express.js framework. Currently I need to make an API call to get some data usefull for my app.

The API call is made with [Request middleware](https://github.com/request/request), but when I'm out of the request my variable become undefined ... Let me show you :

```
var request = require('request');
var apiKey = "FOOFOO-FOOFOO-FOO-FOO-FOOFOO-FOOFOO";
var characters = [];
var gw2data;
var i = 0;

module.exports.account = function() {
    request('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/characters/?access_token=' + apiKey, function (error, response, body) {
        gw2data = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log('out request ' + gw2data); // {name1, name2 ...}
        for (i; i < gw2data.length; i++) {
            getCharacInfo(gw2data[i], i);
        }
    });
    console.log('out request ' + characters); // undefined
    return characters;
};

function getCharacInfo (name, position) {
    request('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/characters/' + name + '/?access_token=' + apiKey, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            characters[position] = JSON.parse(body);
        }
    });
}
```

I don't understand why the gw2data variable become undefined when I go out of the request ... Someone can explain me ?

**EDIT :** I come to you because my problem has changed, I now need to make an API call loop in my first API call, same async problem I guess.

The previous code has evoluate with previous answers :

```
module.exports.account = function(cb) {
    var request = require('request');
    var apiKey = "FOOFOO-FOOFOO-FOO-FOO-FOOFOO-FOOFOO";
    var characters = [];
    var i = 0;
    request('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/characters/?access_token=' + apiKey, function(err, res, body) {
        var numCompletedCalls = 1;
        for (i; i < JSON.parse(body).length; i++) {
            if (numCompletedCalls == JSON.parse(body).length) {
                try {
                    console.log(characters); // {} empty array
                    return cb(null, characters);
                } catch (e) {
                    return cb(e);
                }
            }else {
                getCharacInfo(JSON.parse(body)[i]);
            }
            numCompletedCalls++;
        }
    });
};

function getCharacInfo (name) {
    request('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/characters/' + name + '/?access_token=' + apiKey, function (err, res, body) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(characters); // {data ...}
            characters.push(JSON.parse(body));
        }
    });
}
```

And the call of this function :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var charactersInfos = require('../models/account');
    charactersInfos.account(function(err, gw2data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('request failed:', err.message);
        } else {
            res.render('index', {
                persos : gw2data
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, when I return the characters array, it's always an empty array, but when I check in my function getCharacInfo, the array contains the data ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1):

The reason `gw2data` is `undefined` in the second `console.log` is because your logging it too early. `request` is an *asynchronous* operation therefore it will *return* immediately...however, that doesn't mean the callback will.

So basically what your doing is logging `gw2data` *before* it's actually been set. When dealing with asynchronous operations the best approach is to generally make your own method asynchronous as well which can be accomplished in a couple of ways - the simplest being having your function accept a callback which expects the data in an asynchronous way e.g.

```
module.exports.account = function(cb) {
    request(..., function(err, res, body) {
        // return an error if `request` fails
        if (err) return cb(err);
        try {
            return cb(null, JSON.parse(body));
        } catch (e) {
            // return an error if `JSON.parse` fails
            return cb(e);
        }
    });
}
...
var myModule = require('mymodule');
myModule.account(function(err, g2wdata) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('request failed', err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('out request', g2wdata);  
  }
});
```

Based on your syntax I'm assuming you aren't working with ES6, worth looking at this (particularly if your just starting to learn). With built-in promises & also async-await support coming *relatively* soon this sort of stuff becomes relatively straightforward (at least at the calling end) e.g.

```
export default class MyModule {
    account() {
      // return a promise to the caller
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // invoke request the same way but this time resolve/reject the promise
        request(..., function(err, res, body) {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          try {
            return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
          } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
          }
        }); 
      });
    }
}
...
import myModule from 'mymodule';

// handle using promises
myModule.account()
  .then(gw2data => console.log('out request', gw2data))
  .catch(e => console.error('request failed', e));

// handle using ES7 async/await
// NOTE - self-executing function wrapper required for async support if using at top level,
//        if using inside another function you can just mark that function as async instead
(async () => {
  try {
    const gw2data = await myModule.account();
    console.log('out request', gw2data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('request failed', e);
  }
})();
```

Finally, should you do decide to go down the Promise route, there are a couple of libraries out there that can polyfill Promise support into existing libraries. One example I can think of is [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html), which from experience I know works with `request`. Combine that with ES6 you get a pretty neat developer experience.

Comment: You save my day ... It works perfectly, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The request API is asynchronous, as is pretty much all I/O in Node.js.  Check out the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) API which is IMO the simplest way to write async code.  There are a few Promise adapters for request, or you could use something like [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) with [promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-promise) support.